# Reading diskIO returns strange devicenames

Tags: go, disk-io

Greetings Stack Overflow community!

I'm currently working on a Go script to fetch disk I/O operations using my API. However, I'm encountering a peculiar issue where the script returns empty values. In an attempt to troubleshoot, I added `fmt.Print(deviceName)` to check the discovered devices.

```
/dev/dm-02023/11/09 16:49:47 IOCounters for /dev/dm-0 not found
/dev/sda22023/11/09 16:49:47 IOCounters for /dev/sda2 not found
/dev/sda12023/11/09 16:49:47 IOCounters for /dev/sda1 not found
```

To my surprise, I'm seeing some unusual device names that I can't quite make sense of. Could someone help me understand why these names might be showing up and how I can accurately retrieve disk I/O operations?

```golang
package disk

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"

    "github.com/shirou/gopsutil/disk"
)

func GetAllDiskIO() (string, error) {
    diskPartitions, err := disk.Partitions(false)
    if err != nil {
        return "", fmt.Errorf("error during request: %v", err)
    }

    var result string

    for _, partition := range diskPartitions {
        deviceName := partition.Device

        diskIO, err := disk.IOCounters(deviceName)
        if err != nil {
            log.Printf("error during request for %s: %v", deviceName, err)
            continue
        }

        if counters, ok := diskIO[deviceName]; ok {
            result += fmt.Sprintf("%s: Read Count: %d, Write Count: %d; ", deviceName, counters.ReadCount, counters.WriteCount)
        } else {
            log.Printf("IOCounters for %s not found", deviceName)
        }
    }

    return result, nil
}
```

Has anyone else experienced similar behavior or have insights into why these unconventional device names might be appearing? Any guidance on improving my script to accurately capture disk I/O operations would be greatly appreciated!